# Adding a parent to selected siblings using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I am new to XSLT have a XML that looks like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
            <FileHeaderRecord>
                <FormatCode>1</FormatCode>
                <ImmediateDestinationName>MEPS</ImmediateDestinationName
                <CompanyBatchHeader>
                    <OriginatorStatusCode>1</OriginatorStatusCode>
                    <OriginatingFIIdentification>10000214</OriginatingFIIdentification>
                    <BatchNumber>0000004</BatchNumber>
                    <recordvalues>22100002225201198876900</recordvalues>
                    <ammendvalues>23</ammendvalues>
                    <ammendvalues>23439358</ammendvalues>
                    <recordvalues>1100002143439359</recordvalues>
                    <ammendvalues>0013439359</ammendvalues>
                    <ammendvalues>9359</ammendvalues>
                </CompanyBatchHeader>
                <CompanyBatchTrailer>
                  <Sderviceclasscode>220000003</Sderviceclasscode>
                </CompanyBatchTrailer>
            </FileHeaderRecord>
```

I want to add a parent called data to recordvalues and ammendvalues(also CompanyBatchHeader can appear more than one time and also number of ammendvalues after recordvalues are not fixed)making output file like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
            <FileHeaderRecord>
                <FormatCode>1</FormatCode>
                <ImmediateDestinationName>MEPS</ImmediateDestinationName
                <CompanyBatchHeader>
                    <OriginatorStatusCode>1</OriginatorStatusCode>
                    <OriginatingFIIdentification>10000214</OriginatingFIIdentification>
                    <BatchNumber>0000004</BatchNumber>
                     <data>
                    <recordvalues>22100002225201198876900</recordvalues>
                    <ammendvalues>23</ammendvalues>
                    <ammendvalues>23439358</ammendvalues>
                     </data>
                     <data>
                    <recordvalues>1100002143439359</recordvalues>
                    <ammendvalues>0013439359</ammendvalues>
                    </data>
                </CompanyBatchHeader>
                <CompanyBatchTrailer>
                  <Sderviceclasscode>220000003</Sderviceclasscode>
                </CompanyBatchTrailer>
            </FileHeaderRecord>
```

I have tried few xslt none of them worked in the way i wanted. Please can someone help me in the same?

I have tried following xslt:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <FileHeaderRecord>

            <xsl:for-each select="FileHeaderRecord/CompanyBatchHeader/recordvalues">
                <xsl:variable name="ammend_count" select="count(preceding-sibling::recordvalues) + 1"/>
                <data>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="following-sibling::ammendvalues[count(preceding-sibling::recordvalues) = $ammend_count]"/>
                </data>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </FileHeaderRecord>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It is able to add data tag across recordvalues and ammendvalues but it is omitting everything else. And I don't know how to solve this problem.

Comment: Post your attempt so we can fix it instead of having to write your code for you from scratch. -- Also state if your processor supports XSLT 2.0, as this looks  like a **grouping** problem.

Comment: Thanks michael, I have edited my post and have added xslt which i think is closest to solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're limited to XSLT 1.0, I would suggest you try it this way. This utilizes a **[key](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#key)** to associate `ammendvalues` with their  immediately preceding `recordvalues` sibling:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="ammend-by-record" match="ammendvalues" use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::recordvalues[1])" />

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="recordvalues">
    <data>
        <!-- copy self -->
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        <!-- copy adjacent ammendvalues -->
        <xsl:copy-of select="key('ammend-by-record', generate-id())"/>
    </data>
</xsl:template>

<!-- remove ammendvalues at their original location -->
<xsl:template match="ammendvalues"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```